# How do I lift the chapter title in Koma-script so it is aligned with chapter prefix?

Tags: formatting, chapters, koma-script

I currently have this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}\enskip}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\baselineskip{-1em}This chapter caption has multiple lines and does not fit into a single line}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: prefix and title aligned with first line only]

But what I want to have the chapter title aligned with baseline of the prefix similar to this:

[image: What I want to have]

I know that to long chapter titles are a pain. But sometimes, they do not fit in a single line and I consider the first result a bit disturbing.

Comment: Your MWE does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `\Longstack` will work for a two line chapter name, with breaks inserted manually.  If you get to three lines, though, no method will prove suitable to look at.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}\enskip}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\Longstack[l]{This chapter caption has multiple lines\\ and does not fit into a single line}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also, the `\Longstack` will not align the right-edge heading text on the right margin.  It's appearance here is merely fortuitous.

Lastly, if you wish to use a table of contents, you will need to use the optional argument of `\chapter` as such:

```
\chapter[This chapter caption has multiple lines and does not fit into a single line]%
  {\Longstack[l]{This chapter caption has multiple lines\\ and does not fit into a single line}}
```

to avoid the stack showing up in the toc.

Answer (score 3):

### A solution with automatic line breaking using minipages:

Minipages need a width specification. Thus I defined a new command `\chapmark` containing most of the `\chapterformat` definition, whose length I can measure. For this I used two features of package `calc`: the command `\widthof` and the possibility to make computations of lengths. The baseline orientation is safed by the optional `b` argument of the minipages.

The new `\Chapter` command (with uppercase C) is defined in a way that you can use the enhanced features of KOMA-Script to be given in the optional argument, but note, that it cannot be used with the KOMA-Script option `chapterprefix` set to true. The default `\chapter` must be used then instead, cf. output below of chapters 11 and 12 in the example.

Also the output for the Table of Contents is not influenced by the minipages, see output below, as well.

Additionally I used `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` as replacement of `\raggedright` for better alignment.

<sup>*Instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` I could have used also a classical `\newcommand` together with tests for empty strings from packages `(x)ifthen` or `etoolbox`.*</sup>

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{calc} % provides advanced length computation and command "\widthof"
\usepackage{ragged2e}% better text alignment
\usepackage{xparse}% advanced command definitions

\renewcommand*{\raggedchapterentry}{\RaggedRight}% for chapter TOC entries
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\RaggedRight}% for alignment in titles

\newcommand*{\chapmark}{%
  \scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\widthof{\chapmark}}
    \chapmark
  \end{minipage}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\Chapter{o m}{% note the uppercase "C"
  \IfValueTF{#1}% optional argument given or not
  {% with optional argument:
    \chapter[#1]{%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth-\widthof{\chapmark}}
      #2
      \end{minipage}}%
  }{% without optional argument:
    \chapter[#2]{%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth-\widthof{\chapmark}}
      #2
      \end{minipage}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\Chapter{This chapter caption is too long to fit into a single line} % ch. 1

\Chapter[TOC entry for caption with 3 lines] % ch. 2
{This chapter caption is longer than the first one and does not even fit into
two lines}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\Chapter{Another chapter caption that is too long to fit into a single line} % ch. 10

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}

\Chapter[Another TOC entry for caption with 3 lines] % ch. 11
{This chapter caption is also longer than the first one and does not even fit into
two lines}

\chapter{% ch. 12
This caption produced with \textmd{\textbackslash chapter} is too long to fit into
a single line}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: output of caption for first chapter]

[image: output of caption for second chapter]

[image: output of caption for third chapter]

[image: output of caption for fourth chapter]

[image: output of caption for fifth chapter]

[image: output of Table of Contents]